# Bind List<string> to multiple Run in Textblock (defined at runtime)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of string I have to display "inline" but with different colors, and which are defined at runtime only.

I thought about binding a `List<string>` (I could have also a list of instances of class with a string and a `SolidColorBrush` property) to a `TextBlock` with as many `Run` elements as the List has (defined only at runtime), but it does not seems to be possible (the `Run` elements are defined at compile time).

A XAML Control such as `ListView` could do it but the whole control seems to be overkill (I don't want the elements to be selectable, I want the text to be as in a `TextBlock`, possibly with a wrap).

How to achieve this ?

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Element1, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="#009837"/><Run Text="{Binding Element2, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="OrangeRed"/><Run Text="{Binding Element3, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="DarkGray"/> ...
</TextBlock>
```

Possible helper class:

```
public class TextRun
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Color { get; set; } // later converted into SolidColorBrush
}
```

Example of result: [image: result]

Comment: You can set the Run elements at runtime too https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9341ee77-ff20-4bf5-a0e1-71e32f9a2a6d/setting-up-textblock-quotrun-elementsquot-from-the-code-behind?forum=silverlightnet

Comment: There is also an alternative to list view like ItemsControl. Tip: if you change the Colour property to string, set it to "Red" and bind it to foreground property, it will work without converter.